# HTML removeChild() throws an unknown exception

Tags: javascript, html, exception

I seem to have a constant error with the function `removelink(id)`, below, which is called AFTER an item is added to a list, with an `onclick=""` behavior. Every time the function is called, an exception is thrown:

> "NotFoundError: Failed to execute removeChild' on 'Node': The node to
>   be removed is not a child of this node."

I am aware, usually that error gives the answer away. However, I double checked the `removeChild()` is calling within the right parent div, and the right child. However, it goes straight to the error.

I am quite inexperienced with JS. Any help appreciated.

```
function removelink(id) {
    var itemname = 'item' + id;
    if(confirm("Are you sure you want to remove this item from the list?" + itemname) == true) {
        try {
            CKEDITOR.remove('leditor'+ id);
            document.getElementById('listeditor').removeChild(document.getElementById(itemname));
            x--;
            limit++;
            document.getElementById("btnadditem") = '+ Add an item('+limit+') ';
            renumber();
            event.preventDefault();
        }
        catch(i) {
            alert("Error Thrown: " + i);
            return false;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

/*
*(Purpose: Creates a new item based on the numbering of var x, an int starting at 0, and initiates the textbox + drawing)
*/

function addNewItem() {
    if(limit >= 1){
        var divcode = document.createElement();

        divcode.innerHTML = '<div id="item'+ x +'"><div class="input-group"><span id="itemNumid'+ x +'" class="input-group-addon">'+ x +'</span><input type="email" class="form-control" name="header'+ x +'" placeholder="Item header"s tyle="border-bottom:none;" ><span class="input-group-addon" style="padding: 0px 0px;" ><button  class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" id="btnremove'+x+'" onclick="removelink('+x+'); return false;" style="height: 41px; width: 41px;" >&#10006</button></span></div><textarea  name="editor'+ x +'" id="leditor'+ x +'"  class="form-control ckeditor" rows="8" style="resize:none;border-top:none;" placeholder="Item Content"></textarea><hr /></div>';

        document.getElementById("listeditor").appendChild(divcode); 

        //CKEDITOR.inline( document.getElementById( 'editable' ) )
        CKEDITOR.replace('leditor'+ x);
        //createEditor(x);
        //$( 'textarea#leditor' + x ).ckeditor();
        //document.getElementById('leditor' + x).className += " ckeditor"
        x++;
        limit--;
        if(limit != 0) {
            document.getElementById("btnadditem").innerHTML = " + Add an item("+limit+") ";
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("btnadditem").innerHTML = "Limit Reached";
            document.getElementById("btnadditem").className += "disabled";
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

In the HTML, I have a `<div id ="listeditor">` that loads up, which contains the `div`s with ids `item1`, `item2`, `item3`, etc...

Inside those `div`s more `div`s to organize the display of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace the line which removes the child with:

```
var itemNode = document.getElementById(itemname);
itemNode.parentNode.removeChild(itemNode);
```

the other problem in your code is:

```
document.getElementById("btnadditem") = '+ Add an item('+limit+') ';
```

you can't override a html node with a string, you probably want to do:

```
document.getElementById("btnadditem").innerHTML = '+ Add an item('+limit+') ';
```

Comment: Awesome that removed that exception, however now I am getting another exception, which stops the function renumber() from being called :

ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

Comment: @user3272700: check the answer again and fix your code.